# how do you parse out the output of script javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a difficult time figuring out a javascript problem. I have script that I does an ajax call via a php script get data. This data is in this format "[12300000,13]"

when I do alert on data, I will exactly get that. I am interested in the values inside the bracket. So this is what I did:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(data); 
var temp = new Array();
temp=myObj.split(',');
```

when I try to do this;

```
alert(temp[0]);
```

I dont get anything back. Is there an easy way to do this in javascript. My whole script is below:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'get_data.php', 
        success: function(data) {
         //when I do alert(data), I will get this format [123000000,45]//
        var myObj = JSON.parse(data); 
        alert(myObj);//this will display this without the brackets123000000,45
                //but when I do this
        var temp = new Array();
        temp=myObj.split(',');
                alert(temp[0]); //does not return anything
         },
        cache: false
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myObj` **is** an array; `JSON.parse` will parse JSON into the corresponding Javascript objects.

You don't need to do anything

Answer (score 2):

You already parsed the string into an array. Just get the first element:

```
> var arr = JSON.parse("[12300000,13]")
> arr[0]
12300000
```

Your problem here is actually `alert()`. Don't use it as a debugging tool. Use `console.log()` and open up your JS console, which will display objects in a friendly manner.

Comment: I could never get that to working. How do get the console.log() working.

Comment: @user1471980: Replace `alert` with `console.log` and open your browser's JS console.

Comment: @user1471980: What browser are you using?

Comment: ie 8, are you guys talking about the output when pushed f12?

Comment: @user1471980: Why in the world are you developing in IE8?

Comment: I just ralized that JSON.parser is not working on ie. I looked at some of recommendations like include json2.js and modify html <!DOCTYPE HTML>, it is not working. Most of the people here use ie8 and I need to make this work for this version. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1471980: Ask a separate question.